# Can two Macs be kept in sync using a single external hard drive?

Tags: macbook-pro, time-machine, data-synchronization

I regularly commute by bicycle from home to work and find the weight of a MacBook Pro a little excessive. My thought is to have identical MacBooks at the office and home and only carry a hard disk on the bike.

So how would it be easiest to ensure that the two laptops are totally synchronised? Would Time Machine do the job or would it be time consuming and cumbersome? Or is there a better way of doing this avoiding cloud-based or network-based sync solutions.

The only connection between the two MacBooks will be through a portable hard drive.

Comment: How many files we talking about? What kind of capacity? Want to sync OS and user files as well?

Comment: I don't think Time Machine is going to help you, it's more geared towards backup and recovery. Maybe placing your home drive on the external HDD is an option? In that way all your files, preferences and applications will be on one hard disk. [Here's an article](http://www.macworld.com/article/1164891/keeping_mac_os_and_data_on_separate_drives.html) on this process. Feel free to ask specific questions about this process here if something doesn't work.

Comment: You can boot from a USB hard drive. Use an SSD and it will be fast enough for daily use.

Answer (score 2):

To keep all settings and files of two Mac's in sync through an off-line method you could place your Home folder on an external HDD.
There are plenty of tutorials on-line on how to do this, I will use [this one](http://computers.tutsplus.com/tutorials/relocate-your-home-folder-to-another-drive-or-volume--mac-48822) to explain the process.

I assume you have a user account `Allan` on the current MacBook Pro (`MBP-1`) which you would like to share with the new laptop (`MBP-2`) through an external HDD named `ExtDisk`. Keep in mind that you should substitute the actual hard disk and user account names.

1. First create a back-up of the user account in case something goes wrong. Time Machine is an option for that, but you can also clone the drive with for example Carbon Copy Cloner.
2. Create a new administrator account on each MacBook Pro. This is for the case that you lose the external HDD for some reason or just don't have it with you. This way you'll still have an account from which you can use the laptop.
3. Migrate the `Allan` user account from `MBP-1` to the new `MBP-2`. [Here's](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5872) an Apple Knowledge Base article on how to do that.
4. On `MBP-1` login to the newly created admin account. Copy the `Allan` home folder of `MBP-1` to `ExtDisk`. You can do this by using the following Terminal command (the Terminal application is found in Applications -> Utilities -> Terminal.app):
   `sudo ditto -v /Users/Allan/ /Volumes/ExtDisk/Users/Allan`
   This command will ask your admin account password to get permission to copy all your files to the external disk `ExtDisk`.
5. When you're done copying, open `ExtDisk` in the Finder and check if the user folder is there and has (roughly) the same size as the `Allan` user folder on `MBP-1`.
6. Go to `System Preferences -> Users & Groups`. Right click on the `Allan` account and click `Advanced Options...`.
7. The `Home directory` line says now `/Users/Allan`. Click `Choose...` and navigate to the home folder on `ExtDisk`.
8. Connect the external HDD to `MBP-2` and repeat steps 6 and 7 on `MBP-2`.
9. Do the following on each Mac with the external HDD connected: login on the `Allan` account and check if everything went right. To verify that it actually uses the home folder on the external HDD, select a file on the Desktop, hit <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> to show the Get Info window and check if the `Where` field says `/Volumes/ExtDisk/Users/Allan/Desktop`.
10. If all went well you can delete the `/Users/Allan` folder on the internal hard drives of `MBP-1` and `MBP-2`.
11. Now you can use the setup as follows:

    - plugin the external HDD and turn on the laptop
    - login on the `Allan` account at home
    - shutdown the laptop at home  (maybe a logout is sufficient).
    - disconnect the external HDD. Go to work.
    - plugin the external HDD in at work and turn on the laptop.
    - use the `Allan` account at work.

Pro-tip: as you will be carrying around your HDD with you the chance that the drive has an unpleasant physical encounter is somewhat higher. Make sure to have a daily backup running, either at home or at work, or if you really want to be sure at both places.

Disclaimer: I have not carried out this process myself. I don't accept any responsibility in the case you lose files.